# CMake find_package cannot find SDL2

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2

Below there is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(sdl_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/lib/SDL2_mingw")

MESSAGE(STATUS "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")

find_package(sdl2 REQUIRED)
MESSAGE(STATUS "SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS is ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "SDL2_LIBRARIES is ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}")

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}-config-)
add_executable(sdl_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sdl_test ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

And the CMake console output is:

```
-- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: D:/lib/SDL2_mingw
-- SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS is D://include;D://include/SDL2
-- SDL2_LIBRARIES is SDL2::SDL2
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_executable):
  Target "sdl_test" links to target "SDL2::SDL2" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Not only the `${SDL2_LIBRARIES} (SDL::SDL)` cannot be linked, `${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} (D://include;D://include/SDL2)` is also wrong. Facutually, it should be `D:/lib/SDL2_mingw/include`.

My SDL2 lib is under `D:/lib/SDL2_mingw`. And there does exist a `SDL2Config.cmake` file. I have write `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/lib/SDL2_mingw")` in the CMakeList.

[D:/lib/SDL2_mingw Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSBip.png)

What's going on here?

---

Update:

if I enable CMake_GNUtoMS when configure CMake for SDL2, after re-build SDL2 I get both `*.a` and `*.lib` files under `D:/lib/SDL2_mingw` directory.

[image: *.lib files]

And then CMake can find the package. However, when compile my project, new error occurs:

```
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** No rule to make target 'D:/lib/SDL2_mingw/lib/x64/SDL2.lib', needed by 'sdl_test.exe'.  Stop.
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/main.cpp.obj
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:89: CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:123: sdl_test] Error 2
```

Comment: Your directory `D:/lib/SDL2_mingw` actually contains **build** directory for SDL2 (note e.g. on `CMakeCache.txt` file). For being able to use SDL2 in other projects you need to **install** it (`make install`), and specify its installation prefix in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable.

Comment: I think I have already build the library via `cmake --build .` command and `*.a` files are the outcome.

Comment: Once again, you need to not only **build** the SDL, but you need to **install** it. The file `SDL2Config.cmake` works only after it is **installed**, along with the libraries. That file doesn't work inside the build directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Thanks. It works after 'make install'. I have tried that before but did not notice that it generate files to another folder.